# Delete MF in smartcard

Tags: smartcard, apdu, scosta

How to delete MF(Master File) in smart card, I am using SCOSTA v1.2b card.
I know MF is the root of the smart card file structure I want to clear the flash of the smart card and use for other application.
 The data written in the card can be edited without authentication

commmand used for creating the MF

> 00E0000010620E82013883023F008A01058D023F03

but not data was written in the card, I was able to delete all the DF (my case:

```
3F02
3F03
3F04
3F05
3F08
```

but not able to delete the MF.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the MF is a quite drastic step, and I didn't find any information in SCOSTA specification, that it is required to be done by DELETE FILE. This is quite plausible, since I can't imagine that process to be performed outside of a lab (i. e. for a card actually used for its intended purpose).

So the only way I see is, to ask for additional information from the card manufacturer (the operating system surely has some additional commands, which are not covered by SCOSTA specification). Specifications typically only state the commands needed during operational phase (i. e. card is in posession of the final card holder) and sometimes leave something to be desired in respect to precision even for that subset. One can't rely on the specification alone.

You will need this information at more than one place, since afterwards creating the (new) MF is also very unlikely to happen via CREATE FILE.

Comment: More likely if we can't delete a MF, then how the SCOSTA OS allows to have an empty MF. Since the MF is void, why it is not allowing to delete it, There is an another case, If I want to increase the size of Data Object under MF it is not possible for me to do the change, whether in DF I can delete the DF and recreate it, what I do for this....???

Comment: @Kanni1303: I see no reason for your conclusion, that the MF can't be deleted. You don't have the necessary information and the same applies for modification of data object, as soon as the length changes.